# How can I fix An action could not be found at the URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/actions/checkout/tarball/v1

Tags: github, github-actions

I wrote some code to test my project and I want to run the test on GitHub Actions 
I have the following workflow definition.

```
name : Testing
on: push

jobs:
    registrar:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        
        - name: Run Django unit tests
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
            run:|
                pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
                python3 manage.py makemigrations
                python3 manage.py migrate
                python3 manage.py test
```

The workflow failed with the following error.

> An action could not be found at the URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/actions/checkout/tarball/v1 run:| pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt python3 manage.py makemigrations python3 manage.py migrate python3 manage.py test'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name : Testing
on: push

jobs:
    registrar:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        
        - name: checkout the repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Run Django unit tests
          run: |
            pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
            python3 manage.py makemigrations
            python3 manage.py migrate
            python3 manage.py test
```

**It splits your step into two steps, one for the checkout and one for the tests.**
The checkout action should be seperate from your custom commands.

It also changes the spacing so that the run has the same intent as the name.

The last thing I changed is that I added a space before the pipe.